# Need to change TableName being passed in to Java SQLite query

Tags: java, database, sqlite, variables, if-statement

I am passing VariableA (barTableName ) to an SQLite query, "SELECT * FROM " + barTableName + " WHERE DRINKTYPE='Beer';". I need barTableName to be able to change, based on what a user chooses. When I hardcode the variable, it works. If I try to change it at all, no matter how far back in the "variable timeline", it gives me a null as the barTableName value in the query. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

DBHelper

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.sixth/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "BarSample.db"; 
    private final Context myContext;    
    public static String tableName = "BARS";        
    String sqlquery ;
    public static String barTableName = MainActivity.upperCaseName;//Pass in the specific bar from the spinner choice
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                this.close();
                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableName;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1) + " " + cursor.getString(2)+ ", " + cursor.getString(3));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels
        return labels;

    } // will returns all labels stored in database

    public List<String> getBeerDrinkLabels(){
        //naming();
        List<String> allBeerDrinkLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

        splquery="SELECT * FROM " + barTableName + " WHERE DRINKTYPE + 'Beer';";

        String selectQuery = sqlquery;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                allBeerDrinkLabels.add(cursor.getString(1) + " Price: " + cursor.getString(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels
        return allBeerDrinkLabels;

    } // will returns all labels stored in database

    public List<String> getWineDrinkLabels(){
        List<String> allWineDrinkLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String sqlquery="SELECT * FROM "+barTableName + " WHERE DRINKTYPE='Wine';";
        String selectQuery = sqlquery;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                allWineDrinkLabels.add(cursor.getString(1) + ", " + cursor.getString(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels
        return allWineDrinkLabels;

    } // will returns all labels stored in database

    public List<String> getMixedDrinkDrinkLabels(){
        List<String> allMixedDrinkDrinkLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String sqlquery="SELECT * FROM "+barTableName + " WHERE DRINKTYPE='Mixed Drink';";
        String selectQuery = sqlquery;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                allMixedDrinkDrinkLabels.add(cursor.getString(1) + ", " + cursor.getString(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels
        return allMixedDrinkDrinkLabels;

    } // will returns all labels stored in database

    public List<String> getOtherDrinkLabels(){
        List<String> allOtherDrinkLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String sqlquery="SELECT * FROM "+barTableName + " WHERE DRINKTYPE='Other';";
        String selectQuery = sqlquery;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                allOtherDrinkLabels.add(cursor.getString(1) + ", " + cursor.getString(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels
        return allOtherDrinkLabels;

    } // will returns all labels stored in database

    public List<String> getShotsDrinkLabels(){
        List<String> allShotsDrinkLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String sqlquery="SELECT * FROM "+barTableName + " WHERE DRINKTYPE='Shots';";
        String selectQuery = sqlquery;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                allShotsDrinkLabels.add(cursor.getString(1) + ", " + cursor.getString(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels
        return allShotsDrinkLabels;

    } // will returns all labels stored in database
}
```

I'm currently try to assign it to splquery with an If statement, based on what is coming in from the other class. I have double, triple checked. The variable coming in IS one of the 3 that are in the if statement, all in caps like is in the statement. I've been working on this for a long while and am beating my head against the wall. Any help would be VERY appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly do you set barTableName? The only thing I can see thats getting set is your var firstBarTableName. Not barTableName.

Comment: Edited it. I've been trying a half dozen different things to try to make it work and apparently posted code from in between two attempts

Comment: I think you misunderstood. In getMixedDrinkDrinkLabels as example you use barTableName. But that hasn't been set there eventually, resulting in an NPE. I would recommend changing barTableName in your ´FROM "+barTableName + " WHERE´ to firstBarTableName, since thats where the table name is saved, isn't it?

Comment: What is there now is what I originally had that didnt work. I didn't mean to post such messed up code. I thought I had an earlier version of it open. I was trying to use the "if" statements as a work around, but it just muddied up my code for this question. I think it is in it's original form now. MainActivity.upperCaseName passes in either "CHANGOS", "LANDOS" or "ANTHONYS" as a string. Those are the names of 3 tables in my DB, caps and all.

Comment: Okay then why don't you use them in your query then? SQLite isn't case sensitive for table names so that should work well. The only thing I can see wrong is that you use a wrong variable in building your query. It is obvious that you get a NPE there if you use a not initialized variable. Maybe you could post a stacktrace so that I could be more specific. OR did I missunderstand you question and you want to modify 'Beer'?

Comment: No. When I pass the barTableName in to the SQLquery, it says that there is a "null" value for barTableName. Even when I know that the variable has one of those 3 values in it.

Comment: Were do you set it then? You set global: firstBarTableName = MainActivity.upperCaseName. Thats it. In all other functions except getBeerDrinkLabels you don't set barTableName, resulting in an NPE. If you don't set a variable it 'defaults' to null, so you have to either set it in every other function you call/use or use another variable, like firstBarTableName.

Comment: public static String barTableName = MainActivity.upperCaseName;//Pass in the specific bar from the spinner choice

Comment: Ah okay I had an old version of the page, nvm then. Are you sure what you pass in is not null? Since MainActivity.upperCaseName looks to me like a static, not an instance call.

Comment: Sorry, fairly new to this. Eclipse wanted to add the static, saying it couldnt make a non static reference to a static thing, or maybe vice versa on that. Would it be better to take it off? If I did take the static off, what  would that mean, code wise, is happening or not happening now?

Comment: When I change the code  and remove the static, I get the following in the Log Cat (its the same things I have been getting all along)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sixth/com.example.sixth.Drinks}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM null WHERE DRINKTYPE='Beer';
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Comment: For whatever reason, it won't accept a changable variable for barTableName. If I go up to the top and hardcode String barTestName = "CHANGOS";, then it will work just fine. But when I make it anything changeable, it gives me that erros

Comment: You can't use a static variable if it needs to change, thats why its called static. What you need is to e.g. pass the spinner to the sql adapter and read it from there directly.

Comment: Thats where the toUpperCase comes from. Its the spinner value, but only the first word, and then made all caps to match the DB tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable in DBHelper.java was static. It was pulling from Bar.java, which didn't exist when DBHelper is originally created. So it assigned a "Null" value to the variable and never updated it later. By declaring the variable as static in Bar.java instead of DBHelper, it allows the variable to pass in correctly and to change as I need it to.